# how to pass a parameter from search container column text from one jsp to another jsp?

Tags: liferay-6

hai i need to pass parameters from one jsp in the search-container-column-text to another jsp. i have displayed the results and i have added hyperlink at last of the column when it click it will open the edit.jsp page and i need to pass the courseid to that edit.jsp from the result.jsp. can any one tell me the solution?

edit.jsp

```
<% 
PortletURL editCourseURL=renderResponse.createActionURL(); 
editCourseURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,"editCourse"); 
%>

<%
        String ns =renderRequest.getParameter("courseId");
        System.out.println("hai hello "+ns);
        //long n= Long.parseLong(ns);
        System.out.println("hello world");
        Course courses =CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCourse(3);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String sdate = sdf.format(courses.getSdate());
        String edate = sdf.format(courses.getEdate());
        String cname=courses.getCname();
        String cdesc=courses.getCdesc();
        System.out.println(sdate);

%>

<form action="<%=editCourseURL%>" method="post" id="register-form" >

<div class="label1">Course Name</div>
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value="<%=cname%>"/><br />
 <div class="label2">Course Description</div>

<input type="text" id="cdesc" name="cdesc" value="<%=cdesc%>"/><br/>
<div class="label3">Start Date</div>
<input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate" value="<%=sdate%>"/><br/>
<div class="label4">End Date</div>
<input type="date" id="edate" name="edate" value="<%=edate%>" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>



<portlet:renderURL var="homeURL">
 <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/view.jsp"></portlet:param>
  </portlet:renderURL>
  <a href="<%=homeURL%>"> --HOME--</a>
```

result.jsp:

```
 <% 
    int n=CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCoursesCount();
    List courses = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getCourses(0,n);
    if(Validator.isNull(courses))courses = new ArrayList();
%>

<portlet:renderURL var="edit">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/edit.jsp"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="delete">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/delete.jsp"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>


<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-courses-were-found" >
<liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%=courses%>" total="<%=courses.size()%>" />
<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.course.slayer.model.Course" modelVar="course" >

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Course Name" property="cname" />
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Course Description" property="cdesc" /> 
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Start Date" property="sdate" />
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="End Date" property="edate" />
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Edit" href="<%=edit%>"  value="edit">
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Delete" href="<%=delete%>"  value="delete" />

</liferay-ui:search-container-row >
<liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container >
```

result.jsp:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter like this :-

```
<portlet:renderURL var="edit">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/edit.jsp"></portlet:param>
<portlet:param name="courseName" value="<%=courseName%>"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="delete">
<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/course/delete.jsp"></portlet:param>
<portlet:param name="courseName" value="<%=courseName%>"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

HTH

Comment: i have build course entity class, using service builder. now i want to add another entity course_user courseid is the foriegn key in it how to add it in service.xml?

Comment: i have written <entity name="Course" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
  <!-- PK field -->
  <column name="courseId" type="long" primary="true" />
  <column name="cname" type="String" />
  <column name="cdesc" type="String" />
  <column name="sdate" type="Date" />
  <column name="edate" type="Date" />
 </entity>
 <entity name="Course_User" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
  <!-- PK field -->
  <column name="courseUserId" type="long" primary="true" />
  <column name="cid" type="long" mapping-key="courseId"></column>
  <column name="userId" type="long" />
 </entity>

Comment: i guess this post is related to "search container" so post entity related questions to its own post.

Comment: Is there a way i can pass the entire row object here? Also 'courseName' where should this be defined? It is used in the portlet param, but i couldnt see it defined anywhere. It should be the selected row course name right? Please help

Comment: Hi, how were you able to get the courseName? I'm confused if where did it came from.